# Will our website be mobile accessible after converting to the PWA?

Tags: angular, responsive-design, architecture, progressive-web-apps

We are developing a wedding website and initially, we set the goal is to reach the desktop clients. The site has complex operations in a few views and an example is provided below where the text atop of the cards is being edited.

Considering the context, I have a question: If we create it as PWA will make it usable for mobile clients with full functionalities?

If someone has a good experience with the PWA, I would like to have an expert opinion. Please, mid it that I am not asking how to convert it to PWA as we can figure it out ourselves, rather, to have it usable for the mobile users in a good way.

The card edit view

[image]

Comment: Just adding a service worker to enable PWA won't make your website mobile friendly. You need to add the css for it to look good on mobile

Comment: @BogdanB this is fine, but, please, confirm if we convert it to a PWA, will it be useful for the mobile users as well (going through the full operations and make a purchase)? WE CAN add the CSS to make it look good for the mobile users :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are designing for desktop first and then expecting to degrade towards mobile, and this is generally a bad idea. The user experience on mobile will be a poorer one compared to desktop, and for a lot of websites like blogs this is an acceptable trade off.

You can't design a software application for a desktop, and then just expect it to degrade nicely to mobile. It's not a blog, and just reorganizing where elements are positioned yields a poor user experience.

### Graceful Degradation

This approach starts with the idea that websites should be designed for desktop users first, and then strip away features for smaller devices. Often the website hides, replaces or stacks elements differently based upon the size of the screen. Where content starts with a layout for desktop as the preferred design, and then is changed as the screen gets smaller.

This degradation in design leads to a poor user experience on smaller devices. While functionality is retained the influence of desktop remains, and the experience of single-handed interaction is less effective because everything was thought out from the perspective of a mouse.

If you are used to designing websites for blogs, e-commerce or other content were it's *good enough* to just reorder things and resize things, then this might seem like a good approach for everything else, but it's not. A software application is not a blog, and mobile apps are not designed to work like blogs.

### Progressive Enhancement

This approach starts with the idea that the mobile design is the *hardest*, and should be done first. Once the mobile experience has been perfected, then the design for larger devices can be taken care of. Compromises in design give favour to mobile users, and there is a bit of influence on the desktop design because of this.

The PWA gracefully degrades the experience from the mobile towards the desktop, and this is why mobile influences desktop.

Comment: So, do we need to re-design for the mobiles and implement the FE separately and in this case, do we need to implement the PWA separately for the website and the mobile?